# form_for nested route url generation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I have two models tea and a review. I have nested a route to create reviews for a specific tea but when I submit the form I am getting a UrlGeneration Eror based on missing a required key. Below is the controller action and route and picture of the error. I am trying to have a user create a new review from /teas/1/reviews/new it is a nested form the issue being it does not save the create.

```rb
Review Model

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tea


  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :rating, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than: 11}

  validates :tea, uniqueness: {scope: :user, message: "has already been reviewed by you" }

  scope :order_by_rating, ->{left_joins(:reviews).group(:id).order('avg(rating) desc')}


end
```

```rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only:[:create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        if @tea = Tea.find_by_id(params[:tea_id])
          @review = @tea.reviews.build
        else
          @review = Review.new
        end
      end

      def create
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        if @review.valid?
          @review.save
          redirect_to new_review_path(@review)
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      def show
        @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end

      def index

        if @tea = Tea.find_by_id(params[:tea_id])
          @reviews = @tea.reviews
        else
          @reviews = Review.all
        end
      end

      def edit

      end

      def update

          @review.update(review_params)
          redirect_to tea_reviews_path(current_user.id)
      end

      def destroy
        @review.destroy
        flash[:delete_review] = "Review Deleted!"
        redirect_to reviews_path(@review)
    end



      private

      def review_params
         params.require(:review).permit(:tea_id, :content, :rating,:title)
      end

      def set_review
          @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])
          redirect_to reviews_path if !@review
      end
end
```

```rb
Route

  resources :reviews 
  resources :teas do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :index]
  end
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 62 of `Reviews_controller`

```
redirect_to review_path if !@review
```

In this line you are trying to redirect to a review show page if review doesn't exist,

hence when review doesn't exist it redirects to show path without an `id`, that's why you are getting an error.

Think carefully where do you want to redirect, if a review does not exist.

---

Per your updated question,

Remove `:create` from the `before_action` in the first line of the controller,

also, in your `create` action change the redirect to

```
redirect_to reviews_path
```

after the `@review.save`.

Comment: So I adjusted to my reviews_path where all reviews are but now I dont get any error in the terminal and I dont see my new review added from the nested route.

Comment: Please add your complete controller and explain what you are trying to do? Are you trying to create a new review and then redirect to that review show page?

Comment: I have added my complete review controller I am already able to create a review separately but would like to also create one in a nested route using  /teas/1/reviews/new to take me there and then save the review and direct the user back to all reviews or all reviews for that specific tea.

Comment: So I made the adjustments but it just renders the page again as if I did not fill out the form I think it is because it is doing the else logic and passing the if loop. I had originally put create in my before action to try and fix that issue. I am also going to add my review model for clarity

Comment: also, replace @review.save with @review.save!

Comment: My guess  is you are not passing the tea_id from the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210078/discussion-between-sohail-aslam-and-steveks17).

Comment: When asking or answering, don't use "edit" or "update" tags when editing your text. Instead, incorporate the change as if it'd been there all along for readability and coherence. We can see what changed and when if we need to. SO is more like an online reference book and not like a message board or forum, so tracking by time isn't as important as making sense.